# Layout related error and query with xml file

Tags: android

Unable to resolve `R.layout.main` error.  what is the reason for this error?

Description

```
Resource Path Location Type activity_yamba cannot be resolved or is not a field Yamba.java  /Yamba_Project/src/com/abhishek/yamba_project   line 33 Java Problem
```

Comment: Rebuild and clean your project

Comment: Be sure that import R is not in the import section. If it is, remove it

Comment: thanks i have done that now problem with xml layout main file is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure `R.layout.main` is there in your project? OR in import statement You import `import com.example.myapp.R;` ? 
 if `android.R.*` is there then remove it and replace it with your R.java import statement.

Also refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error).

Comment: yeah its there.now problem is solved just removed import android.R

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the above error is due to xml file which are not build properly and the variable declared didn't resolve R.Java file.

So if this error occours one should check res folder for error in xml files.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer